# Concatenating conv layers with different filter sizes in CNTK

Tags: cntk

In CNTK - how can I use several filter sizes on the same layer (e.g. filter sizes 2,3,4,5)?

Following the work done [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.08568.pdf) (link to code in github below(1)), I want to take text, use an embedding layer, apply four different sizes of filters (2,3,4,5), concatenate the results and feed it to a fully connected layer. 
[Network architecture figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9Keo.png)

**Keras sample code:**

```
main_input = Input(shape=(100,) 
embedding = Embedding(output_dim=32, input_dim=100, input_length=100, dropout=0)(main_input)

conv1 = getconvmodel(2,256)(embedding)
conv2 = getconvmodel(3,256)(embedding)
conv3 = getconvmodel(4,256)(embedding)
conv4 = getconvmodel(5,256)(embedding)

merged = merge([conv1,conv2,conv3,conv4],mode="concat")

def getconvmodel(filter_length,nb_filter):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=nb_filter,
                            `enter code here`input_shape=(100,32),
                            filter_length=filter_length,
                            border_mode='same',
                            activation='relu',
                            subsample_length=1))
    model.add(Lambda(sum_1d, output_shape=(nb_filter,)))
    #model.add(BatchNormalization(mode=0))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    return model
```

(1): /joshsaxe/eXposeDeepNeuralNetwork/blob/master/src/modeling/models.py

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
import cntk as C
import cntk.layers as cl

def getconvmodel(filter_length,nb_filter):
    @Function
    def model(x):
        f = cl.Convolution(filter_length, nb_filter, activation=C.relu))(x)
        f = C.reduce_sum(f, axis=0)
        f = cl.Dropout(0.5) (f)
    return model

main_input = C.input_variable(100)
embedding = cl.Embedding(32)(main_input)

conv1 = getconvmodel(2,256)(embedding)
conv2 = getconvmodel(3,256)(embedding)
conv3 = getconvmodel(4,256)(embedding)
conv4 = getconvmodel(5,256)(embedding)

merged = C.splice([conv1,conv2,conv3,conv4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with `Sequential()` and a lambda:

```
def getconvmodel(filter_length,nb_filter):
    return Sequential([
        cl.Convolution(filter_length, nb_filter, activation=C.relu)),
        lambda f: C.reduce_sum(f, axis=0),
        cl.Dropout()
    ])
```